# Series of odd issues with mounting SD cards and USB drives

Tags: boot, mount, xubuntu

I'm having a bunch of strange behavior with my SD cards and drives. When I first installed Xubuntu, everything worked fine: I had an SD card (on an internal reader) with two partitions that both automatically showed up, I could insert USB drives and have them automatically mount, and I could unmount those drives using the file manager or gparted.

At some point (and I'm not sure what caused this: maybe a system update?) this stopped being the case. There was some odd behavior with my internal drive: where previously only the main partition would mount, now the boot and EFI partitions do as well. Furthermore, my USB drive and SD card stopped being automatically recognized.

I can mount things manually using mount, but there's still odd behavior, in that I can't unmount them using the file manager: it complains that they're in use. I similarly can't use gparted to unmount them, only the command line.

Finally, there's a very strange issue in that when I tried to boot without the SD card in the machine, Xubuntu went into recovery mode and refused to boot; replacing the card got it working again. I have no idea why that would be happening (other than it's trying and failing to mount the partitions at boot?) since the card wasn't even in the machine when I installed Xubuntu.

lspci returns (among other things)

```
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

but I can access the files on the card.
The USB stick works fine in my Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the changed behavior that you notice concerning SD cards and USB drives are caused by an update of the system for automatic mounting.

I have no other general solution than what you are already using: `mount` and `unmount` command lines. It may help to create shellscripts or aliases to make things more convenient.

---

If you want help with some specific detail, please tell me, and will try to help. For example, what partition table (MSDOS or GPT) and file systems are you using? You can try with GPT and the flag `msftdata` on the partition(s). It might help auto mounting also in your case.